# How to add a filter to Dynamics CRM connector 3.0.0 to read single contact

Tags: data-exchange-framework, dynamics-crm-module

We are trying to set up the Sitecore Connect for Microsoft Dynamics 365 for Sales 3.0.0 on Sitecore 9.2

I need to sync contact from CRM to xConnect

I am in process of extending our xdb model in order to be able to sync custom fields from the CRM to xConnect. And I want to execute the sync only on a single contact for test purposes.

I know the dynamics contact ID I want to test on. Is there a way to add some kind of a filter to

```
Read Contacts from Dynamics Pipeline
```

So I don't run the whole list of contacts each time I test?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have figured a way:

On the Read Contacts from Dynamics Pipeline there is a field "Filter Expression".
[image]

If I create my custom condition "Where contact is my Test User" with one string condition inside to check the contact id - I can include that into the pipeline.

[image]

Worked for me.